# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushTag' of undefined

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

I am trying to integrate google tag manager but after configuration it is giving pushTag of undefined.

These are the snippets

**home.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { CounterService } from './counter.service';
import { NotificationService } from '../services/notification.service';
import { MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetRef } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { GoogleTagManagerService } from 'angular-google-tag-manager';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 constructor(
    private gtmService: GoogleTagManagerService,
  ) {}
  
   ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.forEach(item => {
      if (item instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          const gtmTag = {
              event: 'page',
              pageName: item.url
          };

          this.gtmService.pushTag(gtmTag);
      }
  });

  }
```

**home.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent, BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet } from './home.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent,BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CarouselModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet],
  providers: [
    {provide: 'googleTagManagerId', useValue: '*****'}
  ],
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show us you package.json?

Comment: What if you move your provider to `AppModule` ?

Comment: Thanks David you are exactly correct, I thought I can provide it from home.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide your GTM id in app.module.ts and not in home.module.ts.

Hope this helps.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        {provide: 'googleTagManagerId', useValue: '*****'}
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for showing in snippet, I thought I can provide it from home.module.ts